# TFS - how to create branches

Tags: branch

Any one knows how to create branches in Team Foundation Server? Is there any step by step document? I am using TFS 2010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple.

Select a folder in TFS and right-click. There is branching/merging option there.

I like this document - very easy read

http://howstevegotburnedtoday.com/2006/10/19/document-from-vss-to-tfs-an-introduction-to-team-foundation-server-version-control-from-a-visual-sourcesafe-users-perspective/

Comment: The document was created by Steven St. Jean. A quick google search gave me a few more links including this one: http://howstevegotburnedtoday.com/2006/10/19/document-from-vss-to-tfs-an-introduction-to-team-foundation-server-version-control-from-a-visual-sourcesafe-users-perspective/

Comment: This Steve guy is the king of broken links, it seems

Comment: The PDF link in the article is broken again :P:/

Answer (score 0):

I am also using VS 2010 Premium and I was having the same question as you. Since your chosen answer's link is broken, I've decided to share my procedure to branch with TFS in VS 2010:

1. I opened the "Team Explorer" window usually displayed in the right side of VS 2010
2. I double clicked "Source Control"
3. This opened the "Source Control Explorer" in my main VS view.
4. I right clicked the folder I wanted to branch and chose the "branch" contextual menu option
5. Commit your newly created branch